# How can I get weight of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

User from storyboard or programatically can set font weight as regular, semi bold etc.

I want to read weight for any font label.

I tried `po label.font.description` and font-weight is there and but there is no exposed variable to get weight from font.

Is it possible?

Comment: `label.font.UIFontWeight`

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get weight. you can just check it is bold or not.

Comment: May be This use full:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor.traitkey

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the font weight string name, use the font descriptor and pass in the face attribute.

**Swift 4.2**

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
let face = font.fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptorFaceAttribute) as! String
print("face: \(face)")
```

**Swift 3**

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightBold)
let face = font.fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptorFaceAttribute) as! String
print("face: \(face)")
```

Comment: `UIFontDescriptorFaceAttribute` has been renamed to `UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.face` (or just `.face`) in later versions of Swift.

Answer (score 19):

It seems that `fontDescriptor.fontAttributes` won't return *all* the attributes of a font. Luckily `fontDescriptor.object(forKey: .traits)` will, so we can hop onto that.

Newer Swift versions:

```swift
extension UIFont {
    var weight: UIFont.Weight {
        guard let weightNumber = traits[.weight] as? Double else { return .regular }
        let weight = UIFont.Weight(rawValue: weightNumber)
        return weight
    }

    private var traits: [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey: Any] {
        return fontDescriptor.object(forKey: .traits) as? [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey: Any]
            ?? [:]
    }
}
```

Older Swift versions:

```swift
extension UIFont {
    var weight: UIFont.Weight {
        guard let weightNumber = traits[.weight] as? NSNumber else { return .regular }
        let weightRawValue = CGFloat(weightNumber.doubleValue)
        let weight = UIFont.Weight(rawValue: weightRawValue)
        return weight
    }

    private var traits: [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey: Any] {
        return fontDescriptor.object(forKey: .traits) as? [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey: Any]
            ?? [:]
    }
}
```

and then it's as simple as `label.font.weight`

(This is fundamentally equivalent to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48688000/1288097 but it uses `UIKit` APIs)

Comment: Elegant. I added a var to the extension to convert an IB-defined system font to its monospaceDigit equivalent, something I'd been fighting for a while. Thanks. Can't do code here, but the meat: `return UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: self.pointSize, weight: self.weight)`

Answer (score 10):

Try following sample font extension with Swift 4. (It needs some improvement for all types of font weights)

```
extension UIFont {

    func getFontWeight() -> UIFont.Weight {
    
        let fontAttributeKey = UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.init(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")
        if let fontWeight = self.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[fontAttributeKey] as? String {
            switch fontWeight {

            case "CTFontBoldUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.bold
        
            case "CTFontBlackUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.black
        
            case "CTFontHeavyUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.heavy
        
            case "CTFontUltraLightUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.ultraLight
        
            case "CTFontThinUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.thin
        
            case "CTFontLightUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.light
        
            case "CTFontMediumUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.medium
        
            case "CTFontDemiUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.semibold
        
            case "CTFontRegularUsage":
                return UIFont.Weight.regular

            default:
                return UIFont.Weight.regular
            }
        }
        
    return UIFont.Weight.regular
}
```

Try with label:

```
let label = UILabel()
var fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.black)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.ultraLight)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
fontWeight = label.font.getFontWeight()
print("fontWeight - \(fontWeight)")
```

Here is Apple document for list of [Font Weights](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontweight)

> The value of this weight is an NSNumber object. The valid value range is from **-1.0 to 1.0**. The value of 0.0 corresponds to the regular or medium font weight. You can also use a font weight constant to specify a particular weight.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no direct way to get it. As a workaround, You could get an indication of what's the weight of the font as follows:

```
let labelFont = label.font as CTFont
if let fontTraits = CTFontCopyTraits(labelFont) as? [CFString: CFNumber], let fontWeight = fontTraits[kCTFontWeightTrait] {
    print(fontWeight)
}
```

The [UIFont](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont) has been casted as [CTFont](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfont-q6r), which generates CFDictionary (by using [`CTFontCopyTraits(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1509723-ctfontcopytraits)) that contains the value of [kCTFontWeightTrait](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/kctfontweighttrait). Note that it would not know what is the exact font weight, nevertheless it could be somehow useful to an indication of what is the weight:

> Key to access the normalized weight trait from the font traits
> dictionary. **The value returned is a CFNumber representing a float
> value between -1.0 and 1.0 for normalized weight. The value of 0.0**
> **corresponds to the regular or medium font weight**.

Answer (score 2):

You can play around with font's symbolic traits:

```
// is true when font is bold
label.font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.traitBold)
```

Check [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptorsymbolictraits) for more traits.

Comment: this is working when I am checking for bold and italic style. But there is no UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits for semibold.